# How to handle the initial load of a form in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a form that has a series type of its "from" and "to" dates, a select component that has its products, and another select that contains the varieties of that product.

my problem is that I can't load by default the first value in the initial load.

I have a (selectionChange) that has the functionality of when choosing a product it brings its varieties

```js
this.listadoProductos = this.resolucionDatosCargados['listProduct'].map(item => ({
  id: item[0],
  name: item[1]
}));
console.log(this.listadoProductos);
this.parametros['producto'] = this.listadoProductos[0];
console.log(this.parametros['producto']);


this.listadoVariedad = this.resolucionDatosCargados['listVariety'].map(item => ({
  id: item[0],
  idVar: item[1],
  name: item[2]
}));

this.listadoVariedadCombo = this.listadoVariedad;

this.changeTypeSerie();

}

productChanged(item: MatSelectChange) {
  this.listadoVariedadCombo = this.listadoVariedad.filter(v => item.value === v.id);
}
```

```html
<!-- Producto -->
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="{{anchoEntreCombobox.MD}}">
  <div fxFlex="80" class="bottom-margin">
    <mat-form-field [style.width]="anchoCombobox.FULL">
      <mat-select placeholder="Producto" [(ngModel)]="parametros.producto" name="product" [disabled]="parametros.todoProducto" (selectionChange)="productChanged($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let producto of listadoProductos" [value]="producto.id">{{ producto.name }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex class="bottom-margin" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="parametros.todoProducto" name="allProduct">Todos</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Variedad -->
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="{{anchoEntreCombobox.MD}}">
  <div fxFlex="80" class="bottom-margin">
    <mat-form-field [style.width]="anchoCombobox.FULL">
      <mat-select multiple placeholder="Variedad" [(ngModel)]="parametros.variedad" name="variety" [disabled]="parametros.todaVariedad">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let variedad of listadoVariedadCombo" [value]="variedad.idVar">{{ variedad.name }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex class="bottom-margin" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="parametros.todaVariedad" name="allVariety">Todas</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Formulario]

Comment: If you have access to the angular form then use `.patchValue()` method on that form control.

Comment: How is that implemented, or can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is with the [multiple](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection) directive

As stated in the Angular material select page at the bottom:

> Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode
>
> This error is thrown if you attempt to assign a value other than null,
> undefined, or an array to a . For example,
> something like mySelect.value = 'option1'. What you likely meant to do
> was mySelect.value = ['option1'].

so if your using multiple in a select, your ngModel variable must be an array;

```
<!-- DONT -->
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple [value]="'Extra cheese'">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br />

<!-- DO -->
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple [value]="['Extra cheese']">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br />

<!-- OR -->
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple [(ngModel)]="defaultOptions">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

defaultOptions = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom'];
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yx5m9q-dzbaru?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.html) (link might not work in firefox, use chrome)

Comment: doesn't load stackblitz example

Comment: @Pablobustamante use a different browser (chrome). Have same issue with firefox

Comment: There is no way to load the example